# Does the TARDIS home in on temporal disturbances?

Tags: doctor-who

Whenever the TARDIS takes the Doctor to an unexpected time/location, a temporal incursion by a third part is usually in progress. As always, the Doctor proceeds to correct it. It seems that the TARDIS takes the Doctor where and when he needs to be. Is the detection of timeline deviations and homing in on them a feature of the TARDIS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider this exchange from the sixth season episode *The Doctor's Wife*.  In this episode:

> The Tardis is able to take human form and is seen as a woman, referred to as Idris, so Idris, in this transcript, is the Tardis:

DOCTOR: You know, since we're talking with mouths, not really an opportunity that comes along very often, I just want to say, you know, you have never been very reliable.
IDRIS: And you have?
DOCTOR: You didn't always take me where I wanted to go.
IDRIS: No, but I always took you where you needed to go.
DOCTOR: You did! Look at us. Talking. Wouldn't it be amazing if we could always talk? Even when you're inside the box?

The Doctor is an adrenaline junky, always in search of adventure, and the Tardis is aware of many things across time and space that even the Doctor is not aware of.  So the Tardis, on its own, often overrides the Doctor's destination or controls and takes him where he's needed.  (Which, considering his craving for adventure, is a place he would want to go even more than where he thinks he wants to go.)

It may not be an official feature on the Tardis, and may not be on any other Tardis, but each Tardis has an awareness and intelligence and this one knows the Doctor and choose the Doctor, so it takes him where he is needed and can do the most good.  (As shown in the dialog cited above.)

Comment: Ah. I should have waited till I watched season 6...

Comment: It's not something you'd expect an answer to and I almost asked that very same question on here the week before that episode aired in the U.S.  Hope I didn't spoil too much for you!

Comment: Nope. I started suspecting this much after season 2.

Comment: An additional note on that episode is that while the Doctor refers/hints on occasion to stealing the Tardis, Idris seems to make it clear that she was the one who stole him.  I think it opens up a great deal of thought about who is really in charge of this team.

Comment: @BBlake: Yes, I had that in the last paragraph - that the Tardis knew the Doctor and choose him.